# How to remove the duplicates data in each Table TD and TR in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, duplicates, removechild

I have In HTML Table but in this table I want remove the duplicates values in each `<tr>` and each `<td>` data, See my below my source code

```
<table width="100%" id="l2table">
                        <thead><tr>
                            <th>Time </th>
                            <th>Share</th>
                            <th>Price</th>

                        </tr></thead><thead>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>15:40:01</td>
                                <td align="center">10,000</td>
                                <td>0.010</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>15:39:01</td>
                                <td align="center">10,020</td>
                                <td>0.009</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>15:38:01</td>
                                <td align="center">10,000</td>
                                <td>0.009</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>15:37:01</td>
                                <td align="center">10,000</td>
                                <td>0.009</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I want to remove below tr only

```
<tr>
                                <td>15:37:01</td>
                                <td align="center">10,000</td>
                                <td>0.009</td>
                            </tr>
```

I have tried Like this but wain, Please help us

```
$("#l2table tr").each(function () {
                    var tdText = $(this).text();
                    $("#l2table tr")
                        .filter(function () { 
                            return tdText == $(this).text(); 
                        })
                        .not(":first")
                        .remove();

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here u go :)

```
 function toArrayOfValues(text) {
  return text.replace(/ /g, '').split('\n').filter(t => t).filter((t, i) => i != 0).join()
}

$("#l2table tr").each(function () {
                    var tdText = $(this).text();
                    $("#l2table tr")
                        .filter(function () { 
                            return toArrayOfValues(tdText) == toArrayOfValues($(this).text());
                        })
                        .not(":first")
                        .remove();

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>` in this case is a parent element containing HTML, not text. To compare the html contents of multiple `<tr>` elements, I would suggest  using the `.html()` method instead of `.text()`.